# QueryDsl error. Q classes not generated

Tags: java, spring, maven, querydsl

I try to generate query type classes (e.g. `QUser`) but got errors...

You can find my source code here: [https://github.com/TheNakedMan/remindme.server/](http://UserRepository)

I'am working with IntelliJ IDEA, and it seems like I have working plugin.
Help me, please.

Log message:

> /remindme.server/src/main/java/com/qoobico/remindme/server/repository/UserRepository.java
>   Error:(21, 126) java: cannot find symbol   symbol: class QUser
>
> Error:(25, 62) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class QUser
>   location: interface
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.UserRepository

**UPDATE:**

After `LifeCycle->clean` and run `apt:process` in IntelliJ, I have this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com.qoobico.remindme.server:
>   Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server:com.qoobico.remindme.server:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not find artifact
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server:com.qoobico.remindme.server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: too less information ... sorry

Comment: So, here is my pom.xml  https://github.com/TheNakedMan/remindme.server/blob/master/pom.xml    What kind of information do you need?

Comment: what type of error, log messages, minimal example ... see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, Log message was added.

Comment: remove this dependency from your pom com.qoobico.remindme.server ?!

Comment: or if this is a valid dependency ... run mvn install in that project... after that it is installed in your local repository and you should be able to build this project

Comment: Thanks! After deleting the wrong dependency and command mvn install, class QUser was install!

Comment: But during the install I've got this:  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project com.qoobico.remindme.server: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) ->

Comment: I, perhaps that will not be problem for using QueryDsl...

Comment: @Meiko, Please, add  command run mvn  to your answer, and I will mark answer as useful. Because, there a lot of noobs like me, that will not find this command in QueryDSL plugin instruction.

Comment: Yes you are right, It is not documented. I edited my Post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your sources you did not import the generated classes, for instance:

```
import com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.QUser;
```

If you want to generate the classes without compile and/or install the package use the [maven goal](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) `apt:process`.

You can use IntelliJ to start such a maven goal, use the [Maven Projects window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/maven-projects-tool-window.html?origin=old_help). The window will show you all available goals.

On the commandline you could use the `mvn` cli, which can be downloaded [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). 
Hint: the command from the [help plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html) `mvn help:describe -Dplugin=com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin` will show you a list of all available apt-maven-plugin goals.

You configured the outputDirectory to: `target/generated-sources/java`
To let your IDE find that classes, put them into your class path. Some IDEs like IntelliJ will do this automatically for maven projects, because that folder is the default.

Comment: Ok, now, after apt:process command I have an error that may cleaned situation... My post was updated.

Comment: hey can u please take a look at my post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794079/query-dsl-q-type-classes-not-generated I think you can help me !!

Comment: For anyone with the same issue in eclipse, what worked for me was: 1. right clicking on the project, 2. selecting Maven, 3. Selecting Update Project, 4. Selecting ok.

After that the Q classes were in my path for my Models, so hovering over the error gave me the option to automatically import them.

Comment: in intellij idea 2018.3 it not find the  class